# Is there any accuracy difference between standard DTM editing tools like DT Master and automatic removal of artefacts using ERDAS?

Tags: editing, erdas-imagine, dem

I would like to know whether there is any accuracy difference while editing DTM points using standard photogrammetry software like Inpho DT Master and automatics removal of artefacts in ERDAS imagine.